# Cancel single image download with Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I am using kingfisher for downloading a single image with one of these methods

`KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage`

or

`ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage`

My question is how can I cancel the current download so I can start another one?

I don't have an ImageView so I can't use

`imageView.kf.cancelDownloadTask()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those methods return a task object, `RetrieveImageTask` and `RetrieveImageDownloadTask` respectively. You'll need to keep the task object thats returned and call `task.cancel()` when you want it to cancel.